Пропустить возможность или упустить возможность
В Большой универсальный словарь русского языка:
пропустить Син. <упустить, прозевать разг., проворонить прост., проморгать прост., прохлопать прост.>. Пропустить удобный случай. Пропустить возможность занять денег у кого-л. Пропустить подходящий момент для знакомства.
Исхожу из «упущенная возможность», но никак не «пропущенная возможность».
Как корректнее?


Если посмотреть Карту слов, то можно увидеть примеры, где используются оба выражения.

Упустить возможность. Пропустить возможность.
И она поняла, что окончательно упустила возможность стать императрицей, и смирилась с этим. Валерий Туринов, Василевс, 2023
Заснуть сейчас — значит пропустить возможность вновь увидеть его, доброго, таинственного волшебника, ещё на год.

Мы часто говорим "упустить возможность", не воспользоваться случаем в своих интересах, при этом подразумевается уникальная возможность, которая может не повториться. Выражение пропустить возможность использует в тех случаях, когда повторение удобной ситуации возможно в другой раз.

Это видно и по приставкам: уйти от возможности (возможно, совсем)  — пройти мимо возможности (на этот раз).


Словарь:
УПУСТИТЬ, св. кого-что.  2. Не сумев удержать, дать возможность уйти, убежать, уплыть и т.п. У. птицу. У. бревно. У. рыбу. У. зайца. 3. Пропустить момент появления кого-л., прохода, пробега, пролёта и т.п. кого-, чего-л. Охотник упустил зверя. У. взлёт ракеты. У. момент причаливания судна.  4. Не воспользоваться чем-л. вовремя, не использовать чего-л. в своих интересах. У. сухую погоду для сбора урожая.
ПРОПУСТИТЬ 12. кого-что. Дать пройти мимо, не воспользоваться; упустить. П. все сроки подачи заявления. П. свой трамвай. П. третью серию телефильма (не посмотреть). П. подходящий момент. Когда начнётся подписка? - Всё, уже пропустил.

Оба варианта корректны, но "упустить возможность" более устаявшееся выражение и звучит лучше для уха.

Неужели никакой разницы в семантике слов не видите? Разница, безусловно, есть.  Разве разные приставки ничего не значат? Просто у слов разная частотность использования, отсюда вывод про устоявшееся  сочетание «упустить возможность».

я вижу разницу, мне кажется «пропустить возможность» некорректным. Но словарь приводит такое выражение, и это смутило.

На самом деле, оба выражения существуют, но у них разные семантические оттенки. Мы обычно действительно используем "упустить возможность".  Но "пропустить возможность" возможно в определенных ситуациях.

Не могли бы ли Вы привести источник, где можно посмотреть семантические оттенки и примеры использования?

Я дала ответ по теме.

Зачем давать словарное определение слова в ответе, если оно там указано как синоним. При этом, топя за то, что слова разные.
